# Why are my Pandas DataFrame values out of order according to the index?

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem:**

Executing this code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"1","2","3","4","5"}
index = ["1_i","2_i","3_i","4_i","5_i"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=index)

print(df)
```

Results in this output:

```
     0
1_i  4
2_i  3
3_i  5
4_i  1
5_i  2
```

**Question:**
Why aren't the values in order according to the index that I set it to?
1 should be set to the index 1_i, 2 should be set to the index 2_i, etc.

Comment: You are making a dataframe from a set, which is arbitrarily ordered. Try making data a list.

Comment: @jakub That worked. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are making the dataframe from a set, which is arbitrarily ordered. Try making your dataframe from a container that maintains order, like a list or tuple.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = ["1","2","3","4","5"]  # a list
index = ["1_i","2_i","3_i","4_i","5_i"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
```